# Reciprocity Laws in Cryptography

Tags: number-theory

Does anybody know applications of higher reciprocity laws (i.e. the reciprocity laws "higher" than the quadratic one, like the cubic or quartic reciprocity law) in cryptography?

So far I have found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5935.pdf) that uses the quartic reciprocity law to identify the messages in the Rabin cryptosystem.